# How to detemine if sequence has items and if so return the value in LINQ

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, .net-4.0

I currently do a lot of checks like so

```
If (From p In table Where p.USER_ID = LoggedInUser.USER_ID And p.DATE >= start And p.DATE < [end] And p.PROJECT_ID = ProjectId Select p.Field).Any Then
                Me.lblOverallTotal.Text = (From p In table Where p.USER_ID = LoggedInUser.USER_ID And p.DATE >= start And p.DATE < [end] And p.PROJECT_ID = ProjectId Select p.Field).Sum.ToString
            Else
                Me.lblOverallTotal.Text = "0.0"
            End If
```

however this results in two db hits. (one to  determine if any and then one to calculate the sum.

I am sure there must be a less verbose method to do this but am struggling to find the synta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like (switching to C# as my VB is weak):

```
var sum = (from p in table
           where p.USER_ID == LoggedInUser.USER_ID
           && p.DATE >= start
           && p.DATE < end
           && p.PROJECT_ID == ProjectId 
           select (float?)p.Field).Sum(); // use the correct data type here
```

LINQ-to-SQL (courtesy of SQL-server) has a foible where that gives `null` if there are no results, i.e.

```
 Me.lblOverallTotal.Text = (sum ?? 0).ToString();
```

The key point there (for reading it as VB): switch to `Nullable-of-the-type` and `Sum()` it. Then compare to `null`.